# Jetpack Compose NestedScrollConnection vs NestedScrollDispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-coordinatorlayout, android-jetpack-compose

When is it advantageous to use NestedScrollDispatcher above NestedScrollConnection?  Please list an example of NestedScrollDispatcher in action.

Answer (score 3):

`NestedScrollConnection` and `NestedScrollDispatcher` are made for different use cases in the nested scroll system. There is no "advantage of one over the other" you have to use the one that fits your use case, generally both:

- `NestedScrollDispatcher`: Use if you are a scrollable composeable, to communicate your received scroll events to parent, asking them if they first want to consume some of your scroll/fling, then scrolling/flinging yourself and then reporting to your parent what's left of the scroll/fling after you're done (e.g. if you are a list already scrolled to its end)
- `NestedScrollConnection`: Use if you are a parent of a scrollable child that wants to react to scroll events of the child (e.g. an LazyList with a scrollable item or a layout with a LazyList and a collapsible header). You will get notified  by children if you first want to consume any of their scroll/fling before they do and you will be given the scroll/fling left after the child is done.

Note that the methods of the `Dispatcher` of children basically call the methods of the `Connection` of their parent (`dispatchPreScroll()` -> `onPreScroll()` etc.)

To participate in the nested scrolling hierarchy use the `nestedScroll` modifier which takes both a `NestedScrollConnection` and `NestedScrollDispatcher`. You are, however, allowed to only watch/consume if you are a parent that is not scrollable by itself and only wants to react to child scrolls (which is why the `dispatcher` argument is optional.

In most cases you don't need to worry about it, because `LazyList`, `Pager`, `Modifier.scrollable` etc. already implement the `nestedScroll` modifier. But if you want to customize the behavior you can e.g. pass your own `NestedScrollConnection` to a `Pager`. Also of you build a custom component that uses lower-level APIs to be scrollable, you will need to use the `nestedScroll` modifier.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)) elaborates this quite well imo and also provides an example of how to use `NestedScrollDispatcher`. There is also a [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@sibel.nalop/jetpack-composes-nested-scroll-connecting-a-swipeable-parent-to-its-descendant-s-scroll-1db512f9feae#:%7E:text=Jetpack%20Compose%20supports%20nested%20scrolling,Compose%20provides%20the%20nestedScroll%20modifier.) with a concrete use case of a `NestedScrollConnection` used to make a non-scrollable parent scrolled through its scrollable child.